# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when using Groovy HTTPBuilder for server using TLSv1.2

Tags: api, ssl, grails, groovy

I have a question regarding the use of HTTPBuilder. While using the snippet below to create issues using the JIRA API, I am receive the error below:

The server where the API is hosted uses **TLSv1.2** and that seems to be my problem.

> **Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

Here are some of my costraints/limitations:

- The project runs on Java 7
- The version of Grails is 2.4.3

I know that upgrading the version of Java helps. However, I am specifically interested in learning about ***how changing/rewriting HTTPBuilder*** will help me in solving this issue.

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://jira.xxxxxxx.com/rest/api/2/issue")
    if(projectKey=='Type1')
    {
        http.request(POST, JSON) { req ->
            headers.'Authorization' = 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
            body = [
                    fields: [
                            project    : [
                                    key: projectKey
                            ],
                            issuetype  : [
                                    name: issueType
                            ],
                            reporter   : [
                                    name: reporter
                            ],
                            assignee   : [
                                    name: assignee
                            ],
                            customfield_1 : [
                                    value:'Some value1'
                            ],
                            customfield_2 : [
                                    value:'Some value2'
                            ],
                            summary    : summary,
                            description: description,
                            labels     : labels
                    ]
            ]
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                return json.key
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

Usage:

> TlsHttpBuilder tlsHttpBuilder = new TlsHttpBuilder(['TLSv1',
>   'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'])

```
 class TlsHttpBuilder extends HTTPBuilder {

List sslProtocols

TlsHttpBuilder(List sslProtocols) {
    super()

    this.sslProtocols = sslProtocols
}

protected HttpClient createClient(HttpParams params) {

    def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom())

    def sf = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(sslContext) {

        protected void prepareSocket(final SSLSocket socket) throws IOException {
            if (sslProtocols) {
                log.debug("Setting protocols: ${sslProtocols}")

                socket.setEnabledProtocols(sslProtocols as String[])
            }
        }
    }

    def schemeRegistry = SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault()
    schemeRegistry.register(new org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme("https", sf, 443))

    new DefaultHttpClient(new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry), params)
}
```

}

Reference :
https://gist.github.com/ptaylor/fb5a3abce5c455fbec87f6bfd6386814

Comment: I tried using this. It didn't help me get past the issue.

Comment: Strange as it is working for me. Can you debug SSL connection and share the failure point. Add  " -Djavax.net.debug=all " in your JVM settings.

Comment: Please, have you both checked your respective JVM versions?  Maybe there is some difference.  https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https